# Show that the $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{-(1-p)^x}{x\log(p)} = 1, x=1,2..., 0<p<1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation

I think I'm missing a summation identity or not understanding how to leverage log rules in this equation. If anyone could help that'd be appreciated.

$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{-(1-p)^x}{x\log(p)} = 1, x=1,2..., 0<p<1$

so far I've got to 
$\frac{-1}{\log(p)}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-p)^x}{x}$

since (1-p)<1 I feel like I should use the identity $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^x=\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}=\frac{1}{p}$

and so I'm left with $\frac{-1}{p\log(p)}*\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}$

Obviously that sum goes to 0, which would make the entire sum go to 0. Since it equals 1 I am clearly missing something. Any ideas on where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You can't apply the geometric series formula as you propose. It's not always true that $$\sum (a_n/b_n) = \left( \sum a_n \right) / \left( \sum b_n \right)$$

Comment: Note the Taylor series: $$-\log(1-x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k}$$

Comment: That said, it might prove fruitful to note the power series of natural log is $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}k = -\ln(1-x)$$

Comment: Oh goodness, that makes so much more sense. Appreciate the explanation of why I cannot use the geometric series formula I proposed and the inclusion of the power series of a natural log.

Comment: @ThatOneDudeMike In the future please refrain from using $x$ as an index for sums. That letter is typically used for a continuous variable. Instead you might want to use $n$ or $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-(1-p)^n}{n \ln p}=\frac{-1}{\ln p} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-p)^n}{n}= \frac{1}{\ln p} \ln (1-(1-p))= 1.$$
We have used $$\ln(1-z)=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{(1-p)^x}x&=&\sum_{x=1}^\infty(1-p)^{x-1}=\frac1p\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Since the sum is $0$ at $p=1$, it follows that it is $\log p$.